# Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. I also import FormsModule in ngModule still giving error

Tags: angular-ngmodel, 2-way-object-databinding, angular15, angular16, angular-migration

`[ngModel not working error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7zZE.png)
[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWfFa.png)
[Typescript page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQEC2.png)

> error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

```
 <input required #pod="NgModel" pattern="^(?! )[a-zA-Z0-9/\.&()]*(?<! )$" value="PORT_OF_DISCHARGE" type="text" id="PORT_OF_DISCHARGE" class="searchField" placeholder="Port Of Loading." [(ngModel)]="PODName" name="PORT_OF_DISCHARGE"> 
<`div *ngIf="pod.errors && (pod.invalid && pod.touched) || (userForm.submitted && pod.invalid)">



>I am trying to update my angular project 15 to 16. Now this error encountered in various places,
Angular CLI: 16.1.5
Node: 18.10.0
```